# How to add a function to $validators in a AngularJS Material form field?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-material

I made a custom directive that represents a form field validator, called "assetDisabled". In the HTML, i've included the directive as attribute of the parent tag, but apparently the fourth argument (ctrl) is passed as one-way data bind, because in parent controller my function wasn't added to $validators array of the field named "asset".

I've already read all the examples for custom directive in Angularjs docs.

The parent tag:

```
<md-autocomplete flex
    required
    id="asset"
    name="asset"
    md-no-cache="true"
    md-min-length="0"
    md-input-name="asset"
    md-floating-label="Asset"
    ng-model="vm.selectedAsset"
    md-item-text="asset.display"
    md-selected-item="vm.selectedAsset"
    md-search-text="vm.searchAssetText"
    disabled-asset="{{vm.selectedAsset}}"
    md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template"
    md-items="asset in vm.querySearch(vm.assets, vm.searchAssetText)">

    .....
    <div ng-messages="addIncident.asset.$error" ng-if="addIncident.asset.$touched">
        <div ng-message="disabled-asset">Error message</div>
    </div>
</md-autocomplete>
```

The directive disabledAsset:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.directives')
        .directive('disabledAsset', disabledAsset);

    /* @ngInject */
    function disabledAsset() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            required: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
                if(!ctrl) return;

                ctrl.$validators.disabledAsset = function (asset) {
                    return (asset && asset.status === 'DISABLED') ? hasPermission() : true;
                }

                function hasPermission() {
                    ...
                }

                attrs.$observe('selectedAsset', function () {
                    ctrl.$validate();
                })
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

I just want my function to be added in the asset field $validators!!!

Comment: AngularJS Material does weird things like copy directives to interior elements and destroy the original element!!! It might be wise to file an issue on the AngularJS Material GitHub!!!

Comment: @georgeawg I already suspected it was MD. I could do what you suggested, but I need this change for tomorrow. :/ Thank you anyway.